# Wormhole Attack Implementation -Sensors

Tags: java, c++, networking, network-programming, nodes

I am trying to implement a  wormhole attack detection program for network sensors. I have looked around the internet for source code on this, but have found none. Does anyone know where to find source code for Wormhole sensor Attacks (for simulation purposes) or wormhole detection? If so, where?. It can be in any programming language. Thanks everyone.

Note: I know there are documents out there with Psuedocode on them that I can recreate, but I was wondering if there is source code already out there in order to save me some time. If not,then I'll code it.

Edit: I'll even take ones with Psuedocode right now.

Comment: Inverted tachyon beam from deflector dish tbh

Comment: Thanks dude, but I am being serious about this.

Comment: Get a wired router? Seriously though this is a massive topic and project that people write thesis about. You aren't going to find readily available complete code examples as the problem hasn't really been adequately solved yet.

Comment: I know, I'm working on one, I just wanted to ask the community if anyone knew of any readily available code available. I have searched and found nothing, I just didn't want to recreate the wheel if I didn't need to.

Comment: Also a wired router doesn't work in a mobile sensor network sorry....

Comment: @TheChes44 I would recommend contacting the authors of published academic papers. They may be willing to share their simulation code. At least it's worth a try.

Comment: I mean I am, but some will not send it. Just how authors are, but I will keep that in mind though. Thanks.

Comment: Do some lit review, read how people went about this problem. Choose best methods, i know its hard what others did by reading academic paper. I would use Opnet first to try to simulate some of the ideas used by various authors.

Comment: @shobhonk I guess, I mean, we have a test data generator.the problem is on our project we need on that works and is post detection, which runs into a lot of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wormhole attack has a lot of cases we should keep in mind.

1. The network is set up and has no plans to add anymore nodes (easy dont let anything connect but i guess with my limited understanding of ah hoc this maybe pointless)
2. The network is setup and nodes are added often (they look like a normal computer i think changes in the  tables they collect should point to a wormhole set up)
3. the wormhole is not seen and mirrors the other side of the network with out changing the packets at all only copying them (in this case you have to use the time the packet gets to it's target and that is very "resource heavy")
4. The network does not have two sides it has many or one.

I am sure missed other cases but I think it maybe best to explain what your looking into.

I would think that if you have a network with a bridge you can just check to in sure all packets are somehow sent to it.

In the paper you have listed they list forbidden routes. When they find that one is made they know there is a wormhole. say that there is a node on A side named D and it should never link to Q in less then 4 hops that shows us a wormhole.

I think this is easier to answer if taken in parts then built in to one problem.

so if you want try to explain what you're looking for and i'll see what i can dig up or code very poorly. I think finding a program that will sim a network will be nice then add a random wormhole and see what changes.  logically we know the layout of the network but we need a case that will always work and that's hard to come by.

Maybe there is a base case I am over looking?

Comment: I am looking to rewrite the code they have into java right now. Any suggestions?

Comment: you have the code they used? if you dont mind can you post it? I keep thinking about this problem thought out the day. but i'm not getting far i can understand the context. But i feel like i am missing something about the idea.

Comment: They have it on their website, the source code. Trust me in the fact that it doesn't help.I am looking at it and there are no comments at all. I am struggling thru the code. As there is not a correct impmenentation I might just roll with this one and convert it to java.But.....converting C to Java is ahrd

Comment: If I can get this to work in Java I can tweak it the way I want.

Comment: Hell no. The program doesn't even work. The guy who made this will not offer tech support, so I am lost

Comment: I am a c++ guy and only limited to the class room so far but I will see what I can do. I think if we simplify the problem it will be easyer. example(we write a java program that shows us a "ad hoc" nextwork) then we add on the ability to add a wormhole to the next work before and after "ad hoc set up"

Comment: @TheChes44 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1851/discussion-between-dennis-hayden-and-theches44)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and find anything which might be useful:

- A Study on Wormhole Attacks in MANET (uses ns-2): http://www.mirlabs.org/ijcisim/regular_papers_2011/Paper32.pdf
- Wormhole Attack Detection in Wireless Sensor Networks: http://www.indiastudychannel.com/attachments/Resources/112464-22934-Wormhole-Attack.pdf

Comment: Psuedocode of the wormhole implemented would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can ask these students for their implementation. http://www.wings.cs.sunysb.edu/~ritesh/wormhole.html